# Homework - Find where the components belong

Tags: capacitor, resistors, diodes

> A black box has three electrical connections labelled A, B, and C, arranged
>   in a triangle as shown below.
>   [image]
>
> The box contains three components: a resistor, a small capacitor and a
>   diode. You know that one component is connected between each pair of
>   terminals, but you cannot see exactly how they are arranged. You make
>   the following observations with a 9 V battery connected in series with an
>   ammeter:
>
> - When the battery is connected with + to A and − to B a current of
>     3 mA ﬂows
> - When the battery is connected with + to B and − to C a very large
>     current ﬂows
> - When the battery is connected with + to C and − to A no current is
>     measured
> - When the battery is connected with − to B and + to C no current is
>     measured
>
> On the diagram sketch the arrangement of the three components in
>   the box indicating the terminals clearly.

I have had a lot of trouble with this particular problem. The only thing I can confidently say is that the diode is blocking the current in the 2 cases, but what bothers me is that in those 2 cases the currents flow in opposite directions  (counter-clockwise in the third, clockwise in the fourth), which confuses me.

The first 2 cases probably mean that the diode blocks current in the clockwise direction, because otherwise you wouldn't have a current at all, but that still leaves me with the issue of the third case, where the current flows in the counter-clockwise direction, but apparently still gets blocked.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: concentrate on B and C connections

Comment: @Andyaka What I don't understand is why the position of the battery matters. I understand that the direction of the current that the battery produces matters, but why would it for example matter that a battery is between A and B or B and C?

Comment: Well, try this. Ignore the instructions, fill in the three items arbitrarily, and then knowing "where" there items are, see if they match your expected measurements. If not, rearrange until they do.

Comment: Process of elimination, you know there is one component between each terminal   - the resistor will give a modest current reading (easiest to identify) so eliminate it first - the diode will give nothing in one direction and a large current in the other and what's left is the capacitor.

Comment: @JImDearden Thanks, but is this 'black box' actually an electric circuit? I've figured the answer out (between AC the capacitor, between AB the resistor and between BC the diode) but I'm still confused because I don't know why it would matter where the battery is placed.

Comment: @user29855 Yes, it is a circuit (in the sense it connects the components in a closed series configuration) but it doesn't actually perform any useful function. From a DC perspective the capacitor is an open circuit so using a battery (DC) is a good approach. Its a test of your deductive reasoning (logic) and knowledge of component characteristics. The battery polarity is the key. If the resistance had been a 'wire' then it could easily be confused with the diode - but only in one direction. Reversing the polarity would easily identify them because the diode doesn't conduct in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Process of elimination/deduction

**Always start with what you know.**

(i) There are three components in the circuit - resistor, diode & capacitor.

(ii) There are three terminals (A,B,C)

(iii) There is only one component connected between each terminal.

There are **only two possible unique configurations** of this circuit.

[image]

(i) Either the anode of the diode is connected to the end of the resistor (and the cathode to the end of the capacitor)

(ii) Or the Cathode of the diode is connected to the end of the resistor (and the anode to the end of the capacitor)

**Between any TWO TERMINALS** you will have a circuit consisting of the 'component' which is connected to the other two component connected in series with each other and parallel to the component.

By using **DC** to test the components you (should) know that;

(i) the resistor will conduct the same amount of current in both directions **AND** the capacitor in the parallel path (once charged) will prevent current flowing through the diode regardless of polarity

(ii) the diode will appear as a short circuit in one direction only AND the (charged) capacitor will prevent current flowing in the RC parallel circuit.

(iii) Applying the test across the capacitor only the parallel  circuit (resistor/diode) will conduct (*- in one direction it will give the same (or similar) reading as the resistor, in the opposite direction it will show an open circuit (no current).)*

Its now down to you to work out which terminal is A, which B and which C and which way around is the diode connected. For extra credit you could also calculate the value of the resistor in ohms.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That's actually a pretty clever question, +1 for the professor if I could.

This is actually pretty easy to solve once you get past the fact that it looks difficult to solve.  I think it would help if you marked the three points on a piece of paper, then drew arrow showing each of the measurements and the resulting current.  Once you do that, it should be pretty obvious how the components are arranged.

Also, think about what a capacitor will look like to this kind of measurement.

Comment: That might me the problem, I have trouble figuring out the effect of the capacitor. I know a capacitor stores charge, but I don't really know what its effect would be in this case.

Comment: looking at the questions a more "ideal" steady-state view is being sort.

Comment: @user29855, the current through a capacitor is proportional to the rate of change of the voltage across.  Assuming the 9V battery voltage is *constant*, if the battery is applied across the capacitor, the (steady-state) current through the capacitor is...

Comment: +1 to Olin (and all the commenters) for NOT giving the final solution!

Comment: @AlfredCentauri 0..

Comment: @user: You could always measure a capacitor with a meter and battery as described and see what you get.